# Magento Order PDF logo function

Tags: magento

I'm using an add Print order button to print a customer's order (not invoice) and I can't figure out how to get the logo to show up on the pdf. The following is the code that is in the extension but I can't find the function to manipulate it and I don't understand why it's not pulling the logo that I have in configuration. Please advise. :)

```
 $this->insertLogo($page, $order->getStore());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably don't have store logo for PDF set. In admin you should go to

```
System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Invoice and Packing Slip Design
```

and set your logo there.

Now for the logn explanation in case the above won't work :)

insertLogo function is located in class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract (I asume that your class derives from it).

The rows that you should note are `$image = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/identity/logo', $store);` and `$image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/sales/store/logo/' . $image;`

getStoreConfig function is looking for the name of logo image in core_config_data table. You can check if the value is set with

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'sales/identity/logo'
```

If the query won't return anything or will return value that is not an image name then you'll have to set that value first.

If that value is set you should have a look in

```
/your_store_root_dir/media/sales/store/logo/value_that_is_in_the_database
```

to see if the store logo image realy exists and if it doesn't add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check code in that class ($this) and/or its parent class? You'll see function inserLogo there.